# Non trivial responsive grid layout using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to obtain the following responsive layout with Bootstrap 3, but until now I've failed:

md and lg screens:

```
+-------+-------+------+
|   A   |   B   |   C  |
+-------+       +      +
|   D   |       +------+
|       +-------+   E  |
+-------+       +------+
```

xs screens:

```
+-------+
|   A   |
+-------+
|   B   |
+-------+
|   D   |
+-------+
|   E   |
+-------+
```

sm screens (bonus):

```
+-------+-------+
|   A   |   B   |
+-------+       +
|   D   |       |
|       +-------+
|       |   E   |
|       +-------+
+-------+
```

Is it possible?

**UPDATE**: here is what I've done so far: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z5ry0kr0/6/).

My very first attempt used nested columns as @Filype suggests, but I realized that this way I can't move items in-out from nested columns, so I think that's not the right way.

Comment: what have you done so far? would be helpful to have a fiddlejs example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start on how to implement this layout in bootstrap:

```
<!--
+-------+-------+------+
|   A   |   B   |   C  |
+-------+       +      +
|   D   |       +------+
|       +-------+   E  |
+-------+       +------+
 -->


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    A
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    D
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 b-row">
                    B
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    C
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    E
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The result version can be seen in https://jsfiddle.net/dvbnchp4/3/embedded/result/